# Error while converting 'Asia/Kolkata' timezone datetime to miliseconds since epoch

Tags: python, datetime

The time in Asia/Kolkata time zone is `8/8/20, 8:00` (`%m/%d/%y, %H:%M` format). I first converted the datetime to UTC timezone and then changed to milliseconds. I compared the results to online (https://www.epochconverter.com/), there is some difference in the value.

Asia/Kolkata Timezone datetime (input): 8/8/20, 8:00
UTC Timezone datetime: 8/8/20, 2:30
calculated value of milliseconds since Epoch: 1596873600000
actual value of milliseconds since Epoch: 1596853800000

**Python Script:**

```
my_time = datetime.strptime(timerangestart, '%m/%d/%y, %H:%M')
timestart = my_time.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()
timestart = timestart * 1000
```

what is it that I am doing wrong? Can I get some help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you replace `tzinfo` with `timezone.utc`, Python will assume `8/8/20, 8:00` ***is*** UTC. What you want is `astimezone()`. If you don't pass a time zone, it will automatically use your machine's local time [[docs]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone).

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
timerangestart = '8/8/20, 8:00'

# parse the string and localize to your time zone (OS setting):
my_time = datetime.strptime(timerangestart, '%m/%d/%y, %H:%M').astimezone() 
ts_ms = my_time.timestamp() * 1000 # no need to convert to UTC; UNIX time (should) always refer to UTC
```

***Notice*** that by default, Python will assume that datetime objects without a time zone (tzinfo=None) belong in local time - so you could even omit the .astimezone()! However, I'd prefer to set the time zone so that it is more clear what is happening.

If you want to check for another time zone, you could use [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and e.g. write

```
from dateutil.tz import gettz

my_time = datetime.strptime(timerangestart, '%m/%d/%y, %H:%M').replace(tzinfo=gettz('US/Eastern'))
ts_ms = my_time.timestamp() * 1000
```

Comment: I did try the first code, but the results are still the same.

Comment: @Jasmine: what about localizing to your specific time zone using dateutil, did you try that as well?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I resolved it

```
timerangestart = '8/8/20, 8:00'
my_time = datetime.strptime(timerangestart, '%m/%d/%y, %H:%M')
timerangestart = pytz.timezone("Asia/Kolkata").localize(my_time).astimezone(pytz.timezone("UTC")) 
timestart = int(timerangestart.timestamp() * 1000)
```